# Can't install tensorflow on ubuntu 20.04.3 Python 3.6.15 pip 21.2.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, pip

I have been around the mulberry bush for a few days trying to get tensorflow installed on an Ubuntu system.  My specifications are;

Ubuntu: 20.04.3
Python (virtual environment): 3.6.15
Pip: 21.2.4
Tensorflow version wanted: 1.13.1
Tensorflow version will take: anything at this point

I followed a number of answers on the web.  Got a compatible version of Python.  Got the latest pip....

When I use the command;
pip3 install tensorflow==1.13.1

I get;
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.13.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.13.1

when I do a pip_search on tensorflow, it shows tensorflow 2.6.0.
But when I do;
pip3 install tensorflow==2.6.0

I get the same error.
when I use the --upgrade switch to pip, I get the same error.  I tried to install from a wheel file, but the file was incompatible on my system.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "*I tried to install from a wheel file, but the file was incompatible on my system.*" What wheel file? Please also show the result of `python -c "import struct; print(struct.calcsize('P') * 8)"`

Comment: Wheel file....I went to the link posted for the version I was looking for pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.13.1/#files

Comment: Results of bitness check; 64

Answer (score -1):

As per documentation of Tensorflow, version 1's final release that can be downloaded/installed is 1.15. **Below this version are deprecated and no longer available to use in development.**
Read it about [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#:%7E:text=tensorflow%3D%3D1.15%20%E2%80%94The%20final%20version%20of%20TensorFlow%201.x.)

Comment: Version 1.13.1 exists, no problem: https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.13.1/#files. The OP also tried version 2.6.0.

Comment: I downloaded the manylinux and win_amd whl files for cp37 and tried the command;
pip3 install <path to wheel file>

and got the error:
ERROR: tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-......whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: @SteveOlekszyk You've said you use Python 3.6, why did you download a wheel for 3.7?

Comment: This is my first experience with wheel files.  I did not see a python version number on the web page.  Now guessing that 37 possibly means Python 3.7, I downloaded and tried the 36 wheel files and received the same error about the file being incompatible with my platform.  How would I know which wheel file is for which Python version?

Comment: With no leads provided, it seems like the problem is related to the architecture of the Xilinx ZCU102 board.  It is aarch64.  I thought I could build the tensorflow from source, and I followed directions for Ubuntu, but could not get bazel to install, which was a prerequisite for the tensorflow build.  I cannot find a wheel file that works, but now at least I think I know what is meant by "not supported by your platform".

Comment: I found an aarch64 wheel file for tensorflow 1.15.0 here https://github.com/KumaTea/tensorflow-aarch64/releases/tag/v1.15  The file was the tensorflow-1.15.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_24_aarch64.whl  The install had an error of some kind, but the tensorflow functionality I needed was present after the install was complete.